# Base-change theorems for stable $\infty$-categories

Tags: infinity-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry, higher-algebra

Omitting some technicalities, the base-change theorem for quasicoherent sheaves says that if we have the following diagram of (derived) schemes
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X \times_S Y @>\pi_2>> Y\\
@V \pi_1 V V @VV p_Y V\\
X @>>p_X> S
\end{CD}
where the fibre product $X \times_S Y$ is derived, then there is an isomorphism
$$p_Y^*p_{X,*}(F) \cong \pi_{2,*}\pi_1^*(F)$$ where all the functors are derived and F is a (derived) quasicoherent sheaf.

This result implies a commutative diagram of stable $\infty$-categories, namely,
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{QCoh}(X) @>p_{X,*}>> \mathrm{QCoh}(S)\\
@V \pi_1^* V V @VV p_Y^* V\\
\mathrm{QCoh}(X) \otimes_{\mathrm{QCoh}(S)} \mathrm{QCoh}(Y) @>>\pi_{2,*}> \mathrm{QCoh}(Y)
\end{CD}

My question is about a purely categorical generalization of the above. Namely, is it correct to say something like whenever I have two stable presentable categories $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ which are modules over some symmetric monoidal category $\mathscr{S}$, together with left adjoints to the functors $p_{A,*}: \mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{S}$
and $p_{B,*}: \mathscr{B} \to \mathscr{S}$, that we would have a similar commutative diagram looking like
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathscr{A} @>p_{A,*}>> \mathscr{S}\\
@V \pi_1^* V V @VV p_B^* V\\
\mathscr{A} \otimes_{\mathscr{S}} \mathscr{B} @>>\pi_{2,*}> \mathscr{B}
\end{CD}

I feel like such a statement should exist, and I'm hoping it is written somewhere in the literature or is easy to prove for an expert. Thanks in advance.